# websocket creating new connection every second

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I have an angular 5 application which uses a socket.io-client to connect to a websocket server which is hosted on google cloud platform. However instead of opening 1 connection, I see in the browser multiple connection being created, with a new connection opening every second. I added a debug breakpoint in the code where the connection is open and it is triggered only once when the page load. Not sure why it keeps on requesting for a new connection even though the initial connection was successful with 101 code.[image]

```
  private BASE_URL = 'wss://X.XXX.XX.XXX/';
  private socket: any;

  connectSocket(userId: string) {
    this.socket = io(this.BASE_URL, { query: `userId=${userId}`, transports: ['websocket'] });
  }
```

Comment: Is your web server clustered, meaning, does it consist of multiple processes?

Comment: @angrylemon No, its a single instance.

Comment: Can you show the connection code?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande updated the post to show the code

Comment: The only reason I can come up with, is that the server is dropping the connection, and socket.io has an reconnect option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need more information to answer this with certainty, but I could make an educated *guess* as to what's happening here.

I think the connection code *might* be placed in a bit of code that gets executed over and over again, causing it to show this behavior.

Additionally, if this is indeed a server problem, you can easily see what the server actually sent back, that caused the socket to close. In Chrome, click on the "name" of the request in the "Network" tab, and then click on "Frames" tab - that should show you exactly what kind of information travelled between the client and the server.